# Conjuage priors for linear combination

Tags: normal-distribution, references, linear, conjugate-prior

My knowledge of statistics in general and Bayesian statistics in particular is limited. With that in mind, I would sincerely appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem that I have been trying to solve for quite some time. Hopefully I got the specification and wording correct. I am happy to clarify if something is unclear.

I have a pair of parameters, $s_1$ and $s_2$. Each $s_i$ is a vector $(s_{iA}, s_{iB})^T$.

New information about $s_1, s_2$ is obtained from sampling the following process:

$
y = 
\begin{pmatrix} X_1 & X_2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} s_1 + e_1  \\ s_2 + e_2 \end{pmatrix} 
$

where $e_i$ is a error vector $(e_{iA}, e_{iB})^T$ drawn fron a zero mean Normal distribution with a 2x2 covariance matrix $\Sigma_i$ and

$X_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$
,
$X_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

For shorter notation let:

$X = \begin{pmatrix} X_1 & X_2 \end{pmatrix}$,
$s = \begin{pmatrix} s_1 \\ s_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \Sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \Sigma_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Note that $\Sigma$ is a block diagonal matrix since the error vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ are indpendent.

$y$ is then Normally distributed:

$Y\sim N(X s, X \Sigma X^T)$

The parameters of the model are: $\{s_1, \Sigma_1, s_2, \Sigma_2\}$ and
the likelihood function for $y$ is the density function of $Y$:

$f(y|s_1, \Sigma_1,s_2, \Sigma_2)$,

My objective is to find a conjugate prior for the likelihood $f(y|s_1, \Sigma_1,s_2, \Sigma_2)$ and a closed form expression for the posterior:

$f(s_1, \Sigma_1,s_2, \Sigma_2|y)$

Does this likelihood have a conjugate prior?

What is the conjugate prior?

How do I update the hyperparameters of such a conjugate prior (given a single observation of $y$)?

(My best attempt has been using to 2 (Inverse) Wishart distributions for $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, and conditioned on $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, a single Normal distribution for $s$. However, I have not been able to factor out $\Sigma$ in the trace expression (after after completing the square in the quadratic form for the hyperparameter for $s$.)

**Update 2019-11-12:**

Since I have not found the solution to my question even though it should be in most textbooks, let me elaborate on a simpler special case.

Consider the special case where $
\Sigma_i = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{iA}^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_{iB}^2
\end{pmatrix}
$
This imlplies that the likelihood can be written:
$f(y|s_1, \Sigma_1,s_2, \Sigma_2) 
= 
f(y_1|s_{1A}, s_{2B}, \sigma_{1A}^2,\sigma_{2B}^2)
f(y_2|s_{1B}, s_{2A}, \sigma_{1B}^2,\sigma_{2A}^2)
$

The priors for $(s_{1A}, s_{2B}, \sigma_{1A}^2,\sigma_{2B}^2)$ and $(s_{1B}, s_{2A}, \sigma_{1B}^2,\sigma_{2A}^2)$ can be updated separately but with the identical logic.

Lets consider $(s_{1A}, s_{2B}, \sigma_{1A}^2,\sigma_{2B}^2)$ and note that:

$Y_1 \sim N(s_{1A}-s_{2B}, \sigma_{1A}^2+\sigma_{2B}^2)$

Lets try with the following beliefs about our parameters:

$
(s_{1A},\sigma_{1A}^2) \sim NIG(u_{1A},\lambda_{1A},\alpha_{1A},\beta_{1A})
$

and

$
(s_{2B},\sigma_{2B}^2) \sim NIG(u_{2B},\lambda_{2B},\alpha_{2B},\beta_{2B})
$

The exponent in the numerator in Bayes formula for updating the priors would then be proportional to:

$
\frac{(y_1-s_{1A}+s_{2B})^2}{2(\sigma_{1A}^2+\sigma_{2B}^2)}
+
\frac{2\beta_{1A} + \lambda_{1A}(s_{1A}-\mu_{1A})^2}
{2\sigma_{1A}^2}
+
\frac{2\beta_{2B} + \lambda_{2B}(s_{2B}-\mu_{2B})^2}
{2\sigma_{2B}^2}
$

It seems to me that in order to proceed, it is neccessary to write $(\sigma_{1A}^2+\sigma_{2B}^2)^{-1}$ as a sum of $(\sigma_{1A}^2)^{-1}$ and $(\sigma_{2B}^2)^{-1}$. Using Woodbury matrix identity this can be rewritten as:

$
(2\sigma_{1A}^2)^{-1}
+
(2\sigma_{2B}^2)^{-1} 
- 
\frac{\sigma_{1A}^2 / \sigma_{2B}^2+\sigma_{2B}^2/\sigma_{1A}^2}{2(\sigma_{1A}^2+\sigma_{2B}^2)}
$

And at this stage I do not know how to proceed since the thrid term contains $\sigma_{2A}^2$ and $\sigma_{2B}^2$ in a non-additive and non-trivial way.

I would guess that the third term rules out any hope to have a Normal distribution as the prior for the $s$ parameter.

Now I would be really happy if somebody could help me finding a conjugate prior, if such a exists, for $f(y_1|s_{1A}, s_{2B}, \sigma_{1A}^2,\sigma_{2B}^2)$

Please forgive me if I made any errors above or misunderstood something, this is all new to me.

Comment: This is a linear model, which Bayesian processing is found in most textbooks.

Comment: @Xi'an, I would very much appreciate a, preferable online and free, resource where I can find an answer to my questions. I have been searching for weeks...  Thanks.